# Django ExtJs 6 : upload file error

Tags: javascript, django, extjs

I'm using ExtJs 6 with Django framework. I want to upload file with ext from. When I submit form, it always gives me error of invalid csrf token.

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Here is my code:

```js
//document upload form
Ext.define('MyApp.view.UploadDocumentView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    title : 'Upload Document',
    id : 'documentUploadForm',
    height: 500,
    width: 400,
    floating : true,
    closable : true,
    modal : true,

    fileUpload: true,
    method : 'POST',

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top',
        labelWidth: 125,
        labelCls : 'formfield-input-label',
        style : 'border-radius : 4px;',
        inputCls : 'textfield-default',
        focusCls:'textfield-default-active',
        //msgTarget: 'side',
        flex : 1 ,
    },
    
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        //title: 'User Info',
        border : 0,
        //layout: 'column',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
         //layout: 'form',
         xtype: 'container',
         defaultType: 'textfield',
         cls : 'rounded',
         style: 'width: 100%;',
     },
        
        items : [
         { xtype: 'textfield', allowBlank:false, fieldLabel: 'Doc Title', name: 'doctitle',},
     { xtype: 'filefield', allowBlank:false, fieldLabel: 'Select file', name: 'docfile'},
  ],
    }],
    
    buttons:[{
     text: 'Upload',
     handler: function(b,e){
         var form = Ext.getCmp('documentUploadForm').getForm();
         var token = Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken');
         form.submit({
            url: '/document/upload/',
            //headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8', 'X-CSRFToken' : token},
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken' : token},
            success: function (formPanel, action) {
                    var data = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
                    alert("Success: " + data.msg);
                },
                failure: function (formPanel, action) {
                    var data = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
                    alert("Failure: " + data.msg);
                }
         });
     }
 }],

    initComponent: function(){

     this.callParent();
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it as param:

```
form.submit({
    ...        
    params: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken')
    },
```

To make sure the cookie is set by django decorate your views with:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def main_view(request):
    ...
```